# Android studio: cannot realize something like Edittext, button?

Tags: android

I'm a very beginer in Android Studio, so I have some questions:
1. First, when I typed something like Edittext, button... In Java part, it showed errors. But when I try android.widget.edittext, android.widget.button, it's become normal. But in the instruction, it's still ok if I only type Edittext, button... Android Studio even suggest something when I just type E, B... So what's wrong in my case?
2. Second, how can I use the Image View? I mean when I saw the instruction video, it could show the image immediately, but for me when I draged it, it's juts a blank with lots of errors.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: These are two different questions and should probably be asked separately.

Comment: @nghia95 Did you see my edited answer ? I think your problem was that you type with lowercase letters :)

Answer (score 1):

When you type "`EditT`" or something, notice the autocomplete dropdown menu that appears beside your text? By clicking Enter, it autocompletes that to `EditText` and also (this is important) add **appropriate import statement at the top of your class:**

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```

This is why in tutorials or wherever, people just type EditText. You can also manually import everything you need but that's rarely how people tend to do it. When you import the class, the compiler knows what class `EditText` is, without you having to use its full name (package name + class name, read more about packages in Java or in your case `android.widget.EditText`). There's also one more thing:

You can import the whole package by typing:

```
android.widget.*;
```

This way you have all the classes in that package available by only their name. This may be useful if you're using multiple classes from the same package.

**Edit:** Pay attention that you will not get auto-complete dropdown if you start typing the class name with a lowercase letter (type `EditT` instead of `editt`).

Comment: Well I didnt see the autocomplete though

Comment: I'm not sure how... Maybe you misspelled? Are you using Android Studio? You can always manually import the classes, but that's boring sometimes. Keep in mind that all class names start with Uppercase letter (so if you type `editt` it might not recognize it until you import the class first. Start typing the class name with uppercase and it will autocomplete for you.

Comment: Well that's not my problem though. Can I add u in some messenger like skype or facebook? I will show my work by teamviewer then

Comment: Well as you wish, milanvucic94 at skype I think. Haven't used it for so long.

Comment: Hi, thank you but I already got the problem. Just because I use the keyboard in my own language. :D

Comment: Oh yes, haha.. the same happened to me once ^^

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to create an instance of TextView. Make sure you are importing it correctly, though.

```
//Import statement (with other imports)
import android.widget.TextView;

//Create the TextView    
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LAYOUT);

//Manipulate the TextView
text.setText("Hello!");
```

2) To use ImageView you first need to drag the widget into the layout (res/layout) from the XML editor, and then you must assign it a width and height. You also must assign it a background resource (can be a drawable). If you click the ImageView item from the editor, you should see a list of properties on the right side of Android Studios.